# Automatically move row based on cell data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Out" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() == "TRUE") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Returned/Billed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove the entire row based on the answer in column 10, or J. Once it is removed from sheet "Out", I need to have it added to sheet "Returned/Billed". What I don't get, is it was working when I first added this code. But now it's not working.

I do have this spreadsheet linked to a AppSheet app that only I have access to and use. But when I change column 10/J to TRUE, it's not making the change.

I also got this email last night from Google:

```
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
4/3/17 8:27 PM  onEdit  TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of undefined. (line 3, file "Code")  time-based  4/3/17 8:27 PM
```

How do I get this to run properly so I can use the app I created?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

most AppSheet questions are asked and answered at http://community.appsheet.com

To your question, it sounds like you want to have an onEdit trigger fire on the spreadsheet as a result of an update captured via the AppSheet app. Unfortunately, this will not work. You will need to use a timed trigger instead.